# conditional sum not working on certain datatypes

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a conditional sum in my grouping

=sum(iif(Fields!Letter.Value="Service",0,Fields!Mailed.Value))

I keep getting the #error on half the fields.  There all numbers.  In my proc im calling the fields that are erroring outare doing a calculation.  I tried putting those into a subquery and calling and it errored out.  Im not sure where to go from here.

Any ideas on why this may be and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you give more information please? "In my proc im calling the fields that are erroring outare doing a calculation." doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIf Condtion Returns as object .Parse the object to Numeric like decimal or integer and sum .

Answer (score 2):

This snippet shows a solution:

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!Status.value = "Value a", Cdbl(Fields!Payment.Value), 0.0))
```

Worked for me. Apparently you have to set the same data type in both results either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to check that data types that you are using